# Cytoscape.js - positioning multiple layouts

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am currently using Cytoscape.js to display a variable amount of nodes using the circle layout. I now want/need to add additional groups of nodes around the original circle, with each group also represented in a circle layout.

The resulting visualization would look something like this: [image: example layout]

(where each circle is a circle layout of nodes)

The additional groups don't necessarily need to be directly around the original layout, as the amount of circles also varies. I mostly just need to position the layouts such that they don't overlap each other.

I was able to add the additional groups as individual layouts, but I am unsure how to go about positioning them. I checked the docs and unless I missed something obvious, I didn't see how to accomplish what I need. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `boundingBox` of each layout to tell it where the bounds of the nodes in the layout should be.  Specifying a `boundingBox` tells the layout to put the nodes within the box.  Make sure to specify adequate space and set your overlap-avoidance options appropriately.  Overlap avoidance can make a layout need to use more room than it has allotted to it.